# Gson: serialize transient field?

Tags: java, gson

Is there anyway to serialize transient field of a class? The documentation mentioned it is not supported by default but there might be a way to turn it on?

Many thanks

Comment: The meaning of the `transient` keyword is that it's not supposed to be serialized.  That's the _whole point_ of `transient` -- to stop a field from being serialized.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: It _smells_ like you've had to make a field transient for JPA. If this is the case then remove the java keyword `transient` and use the annotation `@javax.persistence.Transient` instead.

Comment: This is still useful when dealing with 3rd party code

Answer (score 6):

I'm not a Gson expert, but I think you can add the annotation

```
@com.google.gson.annotations.Expose
```

[javadocs here - note that you have to do a few other things too](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html)

Alternatively, you can call

```
GsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithModifiers(int... modifiers)
```

and leave out the transient flag.  Search on "Java Modifier Excleusion" (or transient) in [this doc](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

However, as Dave and Louis commented, it is unusual to serialize a transient field.