# Why Gson @Expose annotation not working properly?

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

I have a model class that fills with server response by gson.
the gson converter factory is:

```
Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
```

I have a transient field inside my model to prevent serialize/deserialize by gson.

```
data class Testy( 
     val id:Int = 1,
     @Transient var isShowing:Boolean = true
):Serializable
```

after getting server response and get the converted gson object, the value of `isShowing` field is `false` while I expected to be `true`(as init value).

### Workaround

I have used below ways but I didn't get the desired behavior:

1. using `@Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)` instead of @Transient
2. as mentiond [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10919135/7261183) adding `GsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.TRANSIENT)`

Comment: used `gson` version `2.8.5`

Comment: why using transient. use "val" instead, so the value would be true.

Comment: @PawanSoni can't use `val`, I want to change it during my process and I need it to be `true` at first state.

Comment: Use Atomic boolean in business logic, not in data class.First time it will true and then chnage as per logic.